# Island Sink Water leak that no longer leaks

Tags: plumbing, water, kitchen-sink

We have house on slab in NC with island sink and were away for a few months Aug-Dec and when we returned to our house it showed water damage in kitchen and adjacent room. The carpet in the adjacent room was dry but water stained and there was minor pooling of water under the sink. We have studor vent that appears fine and we’ve been back in the house for 5-days using kitchen sink,garbage disposal and no leaks. We filled both sinks and let drain and no issues. Any thoughts on where leak originated? Thanks

Comment: Look up. The presence of a sink might make you fail to notice a roof leak being the actual source of water.

Comment: That much of a leak does not fix itself(maybe a drip an hour might).  Except if it is from rain.

Comment: Could the drain have backed up?